# Move object files that require linking to specific subfolders

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

So I have a makefile that has to compile on different machines (solaris and unix), so we need to create different directories for our object files for creation. I've run up against a wall because I cannot quite understand the syntax of creating specific object files, linking with -c as make does not allow me to do so.  Here's a snippet of what I have so far in trying to create different directories where the program should place the .o files, and reference them to build a library in the same directory.

```
OBJDIR = objdir
OBJ = $($(OBJDIR)/$(OSDEF))

$(OBJDIR):
mkdir $(OBJDIR) \
mkdir $(OBJDIR)/sun4sol \
mkdir $(OBJDIR)/Linux
```

Where OSDEF is either sun4sol or linux.

```
libListCreation: list_adders.o list_movers.o list_removers.o
ar -crvs libList.a $(OBJ)/list_adders.o $(OBJ)/list_movers.o $(OBJ)/list_removers.o \
mv libList.a $(OBJ)/

list_removers.o: list.h list_removers.c
$(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c list.h list_removers.c -I. -o $(OBJ)/$@

list_movers.o: list.h list_movers.c
$(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c list.h list_movers.c -I. -o $(OBJ)/$@

list_adders.o: list.h list_adders.c
$(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c list.h list_adders.c -I. -o $(OBJ)/$@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your multi-line rules are missing a `;` between the shell commands.

You should probably have a target for the `$(OBJ)` directory instead of creating it as a side-effect of `$(OBJDIR)` (in general you should not create more than one file or directory per target)

```
$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJ) : $(OBJDIR)
    mkdir $(OBJ)
```

Why don't you have a target for the library, and why are you creating the library in one place then moving it, instead of just creating it in the right place to start with?

```
$(OBJ)/libList.a: $(OBJ)
    ar -crvs $@ $(OBJ)/list_adders.o $(OBJ)/list_movers.o $(OBJ)/list_removers.o
```

Your makefile rules claim to create `list_xxx.o` but actually create `$(OBJ)/list_xxx.o`, that's just going to confuse make. Don't do that. The target should be `$(OBJ)/list_xxx.o`

You're trying to compile header files, don't do that.

```
$(OBJ)/list_removers.o: list.h list_removers.c $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c list_removers.c -I. -o $@
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Definitely did the trick here and now I'm just trying to make sense of the mkdir commands! I'm kind of confused by the second $(OBJ) command having only the whitespace between semi colons. Is that a typo or does that have a different syntax? I'm still fairly new to makefiles so all this help is definitely appreciated!

Comment: Also, I have one more question here; if someone wanted to just run libList from make, how would that be done? I tried running like that and I'm assuming I have to specify the directory like `make odjdir/Linux/libList.a`?

Comment: The whitespace there is ignored, it makes no difference. Yes, that's how to make the library, or you can add a target that depends on it (such as `libList: $(OBJ)/libList.a`) so you can just say `make libList`